# Apache Lucene for J2EE 1.4

Tags: java, lucene

I want to make a Google like search with suggested results. The data is fetched from a Oracle database.

So far I successfully manage to develop the search function in Java 8 and it works perfectlly. But the target machine uses Java 4 and can't be upgraded.

Can I use the fast full text search provided by Lucene in J2EE 1.4?

I know that the minimum sys. requirement is Java 8 but is it possible maybe to recomplie the source code since it is available and use it. If so how can I deploy the new jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use old version of Lucene that supports Java 1.4, for example
https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/2.9.4/

Comment: It seems as a good workaround, definitely gonna try. Can you point me which Lucene version is the latest that supports Java 6?

Comment: There's 6-years old  4.7.2 version

Answer (score 2):

I can provide you few lines which may be helpful to you. If you want to achieve the search functionality, you can use Apache Solr or Elastic Search. In your case, instead of using Lucene jar files, you can use Apache Solr which is a separate web application and also it provides rest calls which you can use in lower version of java. Apache Solr can be in Java 8 which is deployed in another VM.

To get the data from database and to index it, you can use Apache Solr built in data import functionality. You can check the link below for data import functionality.

https://www.searchstax.com/blog/importing-data-into-apache-solr/

Comment: Will check but with the jars I can do it locally on one machine.... That's why I chose Lucene